# Multiple custom user models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a 2 custom user models made by subclassing AbstractBaseUser in app A, which I plan to use in multiple websites.

How do include these models into models.py of different app B?

What I plan is make app A, a portable app, and then build websites which can use one of the custom authentication models defined in app A

I am new to django, any better design suggestions highly appreciated.